# Exporting a stack image from Google Earth Engine to drive results in a very small file

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, land-cover

I am trying to export a stacked land cover type image (24 bands) from the MCD12Q1 product ([MODIS Yearly Land Cover Type](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MCD12Q1)) clipped to my Area of Interest (Rwanda).
I am using the following code:

```
// Import Rwanda boundary shapefile
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Gashakamba/RWANDA_BOUND");

// Load the MODIS Land Cover Type time series and filter only the FAO band
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
              .select(['LC_Prop1']);

// Display the FAO Band of year 2001 clipped to Rwanda.
var image = collection.first().clip(ROI);
Map.addLayer(image,
             {min: 0, max: 255, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']},
             'FAO Band');
Map.setCenter(30.100013463035076, -2.005703260373179, 11);

/* Since the export-to-drive option doesn't allow downloading collections,
we will stack all the images of the collection into one multi-band image */
var rwanda_modis_stack = collection.toBands().clip(ROI);
print(rwanda_modis_stack); //check the propertis of the image to be exported

//Export the image to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: rwanda_modis_stack,
  description: 'Rwanda_MODIS_LC_COLLECTION2',
  region: ROI,
  scale: 500,
  //increase the maxPixel value because it's a large image
  maxPixels: 3500000000000
 });
```

I have two issues:

1. The exported image is only 197Kb on my disk. So clearly something went wrong.
2. The displayed map in the view port covers the whole world. That would mean my `clip()` or `filterBounds()` functions are not working.

Any hints?

Comment: You need to share your FeatureCollection.

Comment: @NoelGorelick I have shared my FeatureCollection as you requested. Can you help me now?

Comment: It's still not shared.  You need to click on the sharing icon in the assets tab and set it to world readable.

Comment: That's exactly what i did. I even shared the shapefile separately @NoelGorelick

Comment: The sharing is working now.  At 500m/pixel, Rwanda is only ~450x400 pixels.  Considering the data is 1-byte and the values are clustered in very large patches (ie: it compresses well), then 197KB seems about right.

Comment: @NoelGorelick, thanks for having a look. I still don't get anything when I try to display the downloaded image in a GIS software (I'm using ArcMap). I only get a black canvas. I'm really not convinced the export aspect of my code is working properly.